# GCM server side

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a tutorial on how to implement gcm (get the data and send a notification to another phone, in this case I'm making a chat app)? I have been looking for one but I only find the client side, which I already have working.

Also how does it work when you don't have access to the internet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have looked at the google archives, yet I  still don't seem to get it, I'm gonna re- read everything , thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial on GCM:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server